# How to bind the bottom of an ellipse to the top of a rectangle in a Canvas. Thanks

Tags: wpf

I have an ellipse and a rectangle. I am trying to bind the Canvas.Top of the Rectangle to the Bottom of the semi circle. I know how to find the top of the rectangle to the top of the ellipse but I can't add the width of the ellipse to the top of the rectangle.

Comment: By the way I now how to do it programmatic-ally but I would like to learn to use the power of binding.

Comment: could you share some of your code what you've tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach doesn't use binding, but it might help.

The StackPanel element is useful for aligning elements next to each other.  Put the Ellipse and Rectangle in a StackPanel, then move the Stackpanel around the Canvas.

**XAML**

```
Canvas>
    <StackPanel Canvas.Top='30'
                Canvas.Left='40'>
      <Ellipse Stroke='Red'
               StrokeThickness='4'
               Height='90'
               Width='90' />

      <Rectangle Stroke='LightBlue'
                 StrokeThickness='4'
                 Height='90'
                 Width='90' />
    </StackPanel>
  </Canvas>
```

**Result**
[image]